# Which monsters explode on death?

Tags: diablo-iii

[Grotesques](http://www.diablowiki.net/Grotesque) are an example of a monster which explodes on death causing splash damage. Are there other monsters that should be given a wide berth when polishing them off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only monsters I know of that explode on death are **Grotesques**, and any monster that has the **Molten** modifier. These guys actually have a small delay before exploding, so you usually have time to run away before the explosion hits

The only other monster I can think of that blows up are [Fallen Lunatics](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Fallen_Lunatic) that will run into you and explode. This really isn't an "explode on death", although they should be watched out for.

Comment: Fallen Lunatics

Comment: @RavenDreamer Thanks, I was having no luck finding the name of those online and am not home right now

Comment: Happy to help!!

Answer (score 1):

One prime example of monsters (which have killed me several times at death) are any unique monsters that have the "Molten" perk. After you kill them, don't get too loot crazy because they will explode and it will most likely kill you.

Not that I know from many, many experiences... :P